# How to display the execution of each parralel Task independenly on Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

### Description:

There is a page, which should display results from two independent asynchronous operations, for example - REST requests.

To display the first task result (doing requests through Blazor lifecycle methods) we need to await execution of both tasks, despite the data from the first task being obtained by service.

### Question:

How to display the result from the first task without awaiting the execution of the second task?

### Consider this code as an example.

Results of the first task will be displayed on the page only after the execution of the second task.

**Service**

```
public class TaskService : ITaskService
{
    public async Task<string> FirstTask()
    {
        const int timeOut = 500;
        await Task.Delay(timeOut);
        Console.WriteLine(timeOut);
        return nameof(FirstTask) + timeOut;
    }
    public async Task<string> SecondTask()
    {
        const int timeOut = 2500;
        await Task.Delay(timeOut);
        Console.WriteLine(timeOut);
        return nameof(SecondTask) + timeOut;
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
@page "/task-test"
@inject ITaskService _taskService

<h3>TaskTest</h3>

<p>First task: @_firstString</p>
<p>Second task: @_secondString</p>

@code {
    private string _firstString = "Init value";
    private string _secondString = "Init value";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var firstTask = _taskService.FirstTask();
        var secondTask = _taskService.SecondTask();

        await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
        _firstString = firstTask.Result;
        _secondString = secondTask.Result;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're going out of your way to do precisely what you don't want, which is calling `Task.WhenAll` to await both tasks before updating your string fields.  Why don't you just await each one in sequence?  (you might have to call `StateHasChanged` after the first one.)

Comment: @KirkWoll: that works Ok if firstTask always finishes first. But it can delay the results of secondTask.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I meant the only change being calling `await firstTask;` and `await secondTask;`.  I believe in that situation since both tasks have begun, that the second task will be initiated as soon as `SecondTask()` is invoked and not after `firstTask` is awaited.  In any case, the OP was pretty explicit about this: "How to display the result from the first task without awaiting the execution of the second task?"

Comment: Yes, with the given timeout values your suggestion  will work.

Comment: Thank you both! StateHasChanged is exactly what I looked for. I have to read Blazor docs more carefully (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `FirstTask()` always finishes first, you can simplify your method as @KirkWoll commented. That looks like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   _firstString = await _taskService.FirstTask();
   StateHasChanged();   
   _secondString = await _taskService.SecondTask();                 
}
```

I have a solution to wait for both, independently. It's not very pretty though.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   var firstTask = async () => 
      { _firstString = await _taskService.FirstTask();
        StateHasChanged(); 
      };

   var secondTask = async () => 
     { _secondString = await _taskService.SecondTask(); 
       StateHasChanged(); 
     };
    
    await Task.WhenAll(firstTask(), secondTask());   // note the ()  
}
```

Comment: It is also might be written as local function:
  `async Task FirstTask()
  {
   _firstString = await _taskService.FirstTask();
   StateHasChanged();
  };`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Henk's answer, but different syntax for comparison.

```cs
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var firstTask = _taskService.FirstTask()
        .ContinueWith(t=> {
            _firstString=t.Result;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    var secondTask = _taskService.SecondTask()
        .ContinueWith(t=> {
            _secondString = t.Result;
            StateHasChanged();
        });

    return Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
}
```